# Processing stuck in step <STEP_NAME>/ParMultiDo(<PARDO_NAME>) for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state windmill-read

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am running a Cloud Dataflow Job using PubSubIO. The Dataflow job gets deployed/initiated successfully. It is invoked by Template. 
But while the ParDo's are running , In one of them I dont see any results in the output and also getting the below error in the pipeline:

```
textPayload: "**Error message from worker: Processing stuck in step PriorityRanking/ParMultiDo(MergeRecords) for at least 05m00s without outputting** or completing in state windmill-read
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
  at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:502)
  at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:83)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.MetricTrackingWindmillServerStub.getStateData(MetricTrackingWindmillServerStub.java:202)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateReader.startBatchAndBlock(WindmillStateReader.java:414)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateReader$WrappedFuture.get(WindmillStateReader.java:313)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateInternals$WindmillValue.read(WindmillStateInternals.java:385)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputFetcher.blockedMap(StreamingSideInputFetcher.java:244)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputFetcher.storeIfBlocked(StreamingSideInputFetcher.java:181)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.processElement(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:72)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
```

It seems from the log that the Processing is stuck from at a Stateful ParDo.

**Apache beam version : 2.16.0
Java version : 1.8**

I have also added :
experiments.add("disable_conscrypt_security_provider"); as a solution provided in some other blogs.

But it seems to not work.Can anybody please help?
Thanks.

Comment: is the count increasing beyond 5 minutes? 5 minutes can be sometimes normal (waiting for a slow external service, etc) - but if the job remains stuck beyond 5 minutes (10, 20, more..), then it may be an issue.... Can you confirm that the job remains stuck long term?

Comment: Hi Pablo, Thanks for the response. Yes , the job gets stuck forever. I can see in the logs that these messages appear after every  05m00s , 10m00s , 15m00s , 20m00s and keeps conituning to appear after every 5 mins. Thanks.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Yes, this is resolved . Removing the side inputs from the Streaming Pipeline worked for me. I am not sure why side inputs did not work for the Streaming Pipeline , But had to remove for this piece to work. Thanks.

Comment: Consider answering your own question

Comment: Side inputs are, shall we say, interesting. Perhaps this bug can shed some light on your issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7745